# Как устранить 504 ошибку в PHP скрипте рассылки

Tags: php

Есть скрипт (самый простой) написанный на PHP для рассылки писем. Но выбивает по 504 ошибке (если на хостинге) при отправлении более 50 писем (а нужно отправить 1000000). Понимаю что не хватает мощности хостинга. Как можно решить данный вопрос. Идеи есть, но в реализации их не уверен.
1. Можно ли как то сделать чтоб скрипт бил свою работу по 50 писем и таким образом мог отправить любое количество писем?
2. Можно ли скрипт поставить на Denwer и смогу ли я оттуда отправлять без ограничений?
Или как вообще решить эту проблему то?
(Скрипт прилагаю ниже)

```html
<?php
    set_time_limit (0);
 $mail1="Тест письма <ggggggg@gg.com>";

    $tmail1=htmlspecialchars($mail1);
    $tmail2=htmlspecialchars($mail2);
    $tmail3=htmlspecialchars($mail3);
    
    if (!empty($_POST) && !isset($sent)) {
  
    $emailer_subj = $_POST['emailer_subj'];
    $emailer_mails = $_POST['emailer_mails'];
    $emailer_text = $_POST['emailer_text'];
    $emailer_yourmail = $_POST['emailer_yourmail'];

    if (empty($emailer_subj) || $emailer_subj=="Тема письма") {
    $mail_msg='<b>Вы не ввели тему письма</b>';
  } elseif (empty($emailer_mails) || $emailer_mails=="Почтовые адрсе") {
    $mail_msg='<b>Не указано адреса получателей</b>';
  } elseif (empty($emailer_text) || $emailer_text=="Текст письма") {
    $mail_msg='<b>Вы не ввели текст письма</b>';
  } else { 
    $mail_msg='Ваше сообщение отправлено.<br>Нажмите <a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'">здесь</a>, если ваш браузер не поддерживает перенаправление.';
    $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers.="From: $emailer_yourmail";
    
    $emailer_text=preg_replace("/ +/"," ",$emailer_text); 
    $emailer_text=preg_replace("/(\r\n){3,}/","\r\n\r\n",$emailer_text); 
    $emailer_text=str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$emailer_text); 
    
    $emails=explode(",", $emailer_mails);
    $count_emails = count($emails); 
    for ($i=0; $i<=$count_emails-1; $i++) 
    {
    $email=trim($emails[$i]);
    if($emails[$i]!="") { 
    if(mail($email,$emailer_subj,$emailer_text,$headers)) $report.="<li><span style=\"color:green;\">Отправлено: ".$emails[$i]."</span></li>"; else $report.="<li><span style=\"color:red;\">Не отправлено: ".$emails[$i]."<span></li>";
    sleep(5); 
    }
    }
    
    $log=fopen("log.txt","w");
    fwrite($log,$report);
    fclose($log);
    
    $sent=1;
  }
} else { 
  $mail_msg='Все поля обязательны для заполнения.';
  $emailer_text=$emailer_subj=$emailer_mails=$emailer_yourmail='';
}

 
    if (!isset($sent)) {
    if(isset($_GET['messent']))
    {echo $text.="<b style=\"text-align:center;margin-top:200px;display:block;\">Всё окей. Сообщение отправлено. <a href=\"index.php\">Ещё?</a><br><br><u>Отчёт:</u></b> <ol style=\"display:block;width:300px;margin:10px auto;\">";
    readfile("log.txt");
    echo"</ol>";}
    else {
    echo $text.=<<<post
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function form_validator(form) {
    if (form.emailer_subj.value=='' || form.emailer_subj.value=='Тема письма') { alert('Укажите тему письма.'); form.emailer_subj.focus(); return false; }
    if (form.emailer_mails.value=='' || form.emailer_mails.value=='Почтовые адреса') { alert('Укажите адреса получаталей.'); form.emailer_mails.focus(); return false; }
    if (form.emailer_text.value=='' || form.emailer_text.value=='Текст письма') { alert('Вы не заполнили поле сообщения.'); form.emailer_text.focus(); return false; }
    return true;
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    form {display:block;margin:20px auto;width:500px;}
    textarea, input, select {width:100%; margin:5px 0;}
    textarea {height:200px;}
    .red {color:#a00;}
    </style>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return form_validator(this);">
    <p class="red">$mail_msg</p>
    <input type="text" name="emailer_subj" id="emailer_subj" value="Тема письма" title="По какому поводу пишем?" onfocus="if (this.value=='Тема письма') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Тема письма';">
    <textarea name="emailer_mails" id="emailer_mails" title="Кто получатели?" onfocus="if (this.value=='Почтовые адреса') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Почтовые адреса';">Почтовые адреса</textarea>
    <textarea name="emailer_text" id="emailer_text" title="Что пишем?" onfocus="if (this.value=='Текст письма') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Текст письма';">Текст письма</textarea>
    <select name="emailer_yourmail">
    <option value="$mail1">$tmail1</option>
    <option value="$mail2">$tmail2</option>
    <option value="$mail3">$tmail3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" title="Отправить мыл">
    </form>
post;
}
}
else { 
  $ret_uri=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header("Refresh: 0; URL=http://".$ret_uri."?messent");
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: 1. Купить VDS, там нет ограничений на рассылку писем в час. 2. Пользоваться сторонними сервисами рассылки, но они платные. Причем вам нужно будет доказывать легитимность собранных ящиков, а при частых жалобах на спам вас быстро заблокируют. Миллион писем вам никто не даст отправить. А спам это плохо.